# Token allowed in PDF string in \section but not in a customized (with \addcontentsline) section command

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

`babel`'s `frenchb` option makes active e.g. `!` character by making it automatically preceded by a `\thinspace`. Such active characters are properly supported in sections by `hyperref`'s bookmarks. But, when I try to create my own section command with an `\addcontentsline` specification, this leads to the well known `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding)` warning, as pointed out by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mynaivesection}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo !}
\mynaivesection{Bar !}
\end{document}
```

What is missing in my (deliberately naive) customized section command in order to get rid of this warning?

BTW:

1. there isn't any warning if I remove `\textbf{#1}%` in this custom section command: rather strange...
2. `bookmark` package doesn't help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not hyperref that sanitizes the argument. The main difference between `\section` and your command is that the `\addcontentsline` is issued for the first in vertical mode. And the definition of the ! depends on the mode:

```
\french@sh@!@ ->\ifhmode \ifdim \lastskip >\z@ \unskip \penalty \@M \FBthinspace
\else \FDP@thinspace \fi \fi \string !
```

The warning disappears if you insert a `\par` (and also if there is no text before the `\addcontentsline` as you are in vmode then):

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\addcontentsline{\ifvmode \message{V-Mode!#3}\else\message{H-Mode!#3}\fi}{}{}

\newcommand{\mynaivesection}[1]{%
  #1\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{#1}}}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo !}

\mynaivesection{Bar!}


\renewcommand{\mynaivesection}[1]{%
  #1\par\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{#1}}}%

\mynaivesection{FooBar!}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can locally redefine `\FBthinspace` to do nothing.

```
\newcommand{\mynaivesection}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mynaivesection}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo !}
\mynaivesection{Bar !}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but (1) aren't the `\FBthinspace` features lost also for the table of contents? (2) is it the way the "official" `\section` supports active characters?

Comment: (1) No, at the time of printing the ToC `\FBthinspace` feature is in effect, so you don't lose it. (2) I have no idea.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: You can easily test the scope of such a redefinition. Simply do `\renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{HALLO}` and then look where the HALLO is.